# Apply Beveled Radial Gradient to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, gradient, swift5, radial-gradients

I'm currently using the following code here

```
@IBDesignable class RadialGradientView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var outsideColor: UIColor = UIColor.red
    @IBInspectable var insideColor: UIColor = UIColor.green

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let colors = [insideColor.cgColor, outsideColor.cgColor] as CFArray
        let endRadius = sqrt(pow(frame.width/2, 2) + pow(frame.height/2, 2))
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width / 2, y: bounds.size.height / 2)
        let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: colors, locations: nil)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context?.drawRadialGradient(gradient!, startCenter: center, startRadius: 0.0, endCenter: center, endRadius: endRadius, options: CGGradientDrawingOptions.drawsBeforeStartLocation)
    }
}
```

This code will draw a radial gradient that looks like this:

[image]

What I am trying to do is make it look like below (which is how it looks in the current desktop version of the app).

[image]

You will notice that in the desktop version the gradient has **blue at the top and bottom** and the **white area is stretched to include more of the text area** so it's easier to read.

How can I recreate this effect? I have tried for hours playing with different numbers and settings in the current code to no avail so far (such as changing the endRadius).

Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: One idea I'm playing around with is creating 4 different views with their own gradients on it? Not sure if this is a good method or not.